# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : Failed resolution of : Lcom/jcraft/jsch/JSch;

Tags: java, android, jsch

I have written a java code in android for connecting to a remote server through ssh. I have added two libraries - jsch and jzlib . But while running the app ,I get the following errors .

[image: program snippet]

[image: Errors found]

Comment: Check your version of your library or check you have properly imported your library, and please provide the complete code for finding the error. it is saying, class not found error. check it properly

Answer (score 0):

Please check activity declare in manifeast file or not .

because classnotfoundexception is  show You cannot  declare Activity in manifeast file /
other reason is  xml file using a class file but class file not found error...